# Setting dataframe by using both iloc and a boolean mask (mask at multiple different index (row) values in the dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, array-broadcasting

I want to change the values to Nan in a pandas dataframe based on the location of Nan values in a different pandas dataframe. I want to do this at multiple locations in the array. So it works if it is at the beginning of the array where the index (row) values are the same. How do I do this if I want to set it offset by 20 rows in the arrow and then 40 rows.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': list(range(0,100)), 'B': list(range(0,100))})


df2_null = df2.isnull()
df[df2_null] = np.NaN


df.iloc[0:4]

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, None, 1, 1], 'B': [None, 1, None, 1]})

df2_null = df2.isnull()
df[df2_null] = np.NaN
df.iloc[0:4]
```

How do I get this to work below?
Because the first line gives an error and the second line reproduces all np.Nan no matter where I excecute it. I haven't been able to figure out how to do this.

```
df.iloc[20:24][df2_null] = np.Nan
df.loc[df[df2_null].iloc[20:24].index] = np.NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe need [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html), which set values to `NaN` by boolean mask by default (only necessary same number of rows and columns of selected `df` with boolean mask).

Also `df2_null` mask is converted to numpy array for avoid alignment by indices.

```
df.iloc[20:24] = df.iloc[20:24].mask(df2_null.values)
print (df.iloc[15:30])
       A     B
15  15.0  15.0
16  16.0  16.0
17  17.0  17.0
18  18.0  18.0
19  19.0  19.0
20  20.0   NaN
21   NaN  21.0
22  22.0   NaN
23  23.0  23.0
24  24.0  24.0
25  25.0  25.0
26  26.0  26.0
27  27.0  27.0
28  28.0  28.0
29  29.0  29.0
```

Numpy solution with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), same principe like pandas solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': list(range(0,30)), 'B': list(range(0,30))})

arr = df.values.astype(float)
arr[20:24] = np.where(df2_null.values, np.nan, arr[20:24])
print (arr)
[[ 0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.]
 [ 2.  2.]
 [ 3.  3.]
 [ 4.  4.]
 [ 5.  5.]
 [ 6.  6.]
 [ 7.  7.]
 [ 8.  8.]
 [ 9.  9.]
 [10. 10.]
 [11. 11.]
 [12. 12.]
 [13. 13.]
 [14. 14.]
 [15. 15.]
 [16. 16.]
 [17. 17.]
 [18. 18.]
 [19. 19.]
 [20. nan]
 [nan 21.]
 [22. nan]
 [23. 23.]
 [24. 24.]
 [25. 25.]
 [26. 26.]
 [27. 27.]
 [28. 28.]
 [29. 29.]]
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it right now and let you know but didn't know about the .mask function so seems that would do the trick.

Comment: Yeah this works great. Yeah that was the trick I had filled to figure out. I had thought of some other workarounds but all of them didn't work because I wasn't converting the dataframe using .values. I am used to using numpy, so still getting used to Pandas.

Comment: @JSpen - Added numpy solution.